# How to find expression for the reduced cost?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I'd like to know how to obtain an expression for the reduced cost for each of my primal variables, after having formed the dual problem.

I have the following dual problem, where the dual variables are $\lambda, \rho^{t,p}, \pi^{k}, \gamma^{k}$.  Everything else in the optimization below is a parameter.  Each constraint corresponds to a primal variable.  The primal variables are $x_a, x^{t,p}, x^k_b, x_k, z$.

\begin{align}
&\max_{\lambda, \rho^{t,p}, \pi^{k}, \gamma^{k}} &\lambda + \sum \gamma^{k} \\
&\text{s.t.} &\lambda - \sum_{t,p} \xi_a \rho^{t,p} &\le 0 && \forall a && (x_a \ge 0) \\
&& \rho^{t,p} &\le c^t && \forall t,p && (x^{t,p} \ge 0) \\
&& -c^{k}_b \pi^k +\gamma^{k} & \le 0 && \forall k,b && (x^k_b \ge 0) \\
&& \pi^{k} & \ge 0 && \forall k && (x_k \ge 0) \\
&& \sum_{k} \pi^{k} & = 1 &&&& (\text{$z$ free}) \\      
\end{align}

How do I obtain an expression for the reduced cost for each primal variable, in terms of the dual variables?   In textbooks, I typically see an expression like the following:  $c^T_N - c^T_B B^{-1} N$, where $B$ is the basis matrix as part of the simplex method.  However, I'd like to understand a general technique for obtaining an expression for the reduced cost, perhaps we can use the above optimization problem as an example.

Answer (score 1):

I reformatted your formulation and put the primal variables in parentheses to make the correspondence clearer.

For $\lambda$, the objective coefficient is $1$, the coefficient in the first  constraint is $1$, and the other constraint coefficients are $0$, so the reduced cost of $\lambda$ is $1-\sum_a 1 x_a$.

For $\rho^{t,p}$, the objective coefficient is $0$, the coefficient in the first  constraint is $-\xi_a$, the coefficient in the second constraint is $1$, and the other constraint coefficients are $0$, so the reduced cost of $\rho^{t,p}$ is
$$
0-\sum_a (-\xi_a) x_a-\sum_{t,p} 1 x^{t,p}
= \sum_a \xi_a x_a-\sum_{t,p} x^{t,p}
.$$

---

Update: I showed how to compute the reduced costs of the dual variables, but you asked for the reduced costs of the primal variables.  I recommend explicitly writing out the primal problem, applying the approach I showed, and then observing what comes out.

Comment: The maximization problem that you're seeing above is the *dual* problem.  It seems to me like you interpreted that to be the primal.  I'd like to know the reduced costs of $x_a, x^{t,p}, $ etc.

Comment: Yes, because of duality, you can call either problem the primal and the other the dual.  But I changed my answer to say "primal variables in parentheses" to match your question.

Comment: Okay.  Also - you helped me catch a mistake in my formulation.  It should be $x_k \ge 0$, and I changed the question and the dual constraint accordingly.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand .  E.g. if I want to know the reduced cost of $x^{t,p}$, then how do I deduce that from your answer?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean.  I recommend explicitly writing the primal problem, applying the approach I showed, and then observing what comes out.